# HTML5 iphone offline webapp

Tags: iphone, caching, html, web-applications, manifest

So i know that "offine mode" is supposed to work when you have no internet connection. But suppose I build a local network webapp, let's say at 192.168.1.100, then I leave my house, and i'm off the network, then I try to hit that address. Will the webapp pull from the cache, or will it say, "you have internet, but the host is unreachable" or some such thing?

I don't want to go crazy with cache.manifests and WebDB's when it might not work the way I hoped.

Answer (score 1):

If a particular resource is listed in the cache manifest, then that resource is **always** loaded from the application cache, even if there is a network connection. So yes, it will pull from the cache.